# Mysql - normalization of database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database and I want to normalize it in an efficient way. I have a table in my database in which i am getting data into column in the form of array. Actually I have three tables (details, country, material). In table "country" I have two column that are (id,country_name). In  table "material" I have two column (id, material) and in table "details" i have four column (id, vendor, countries, materials). In this scenario, each vendor has multiple countries and materials and I am inserting ids of country and material in details table. Here is the screenshot:
[image: detail table]

so how I accurately normalize my database? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need join tables: `details_country` and `details_material`. These tables would store IDs only, the material ID and the detail ID (or country ID and detail ID). Drop countries and materials columns from detail.

Comment: In the sample record you showed us, is it the case that all countries are always associated with all materials?  Or is that not the case?  Also, continuing with your current design, would there ever be the possibility of a vendor having _more_ than one record in the `details` table?

Comment: no there is no relation with countries and materials. also each vendor has only one record in detail table. there is no duplication of vendor in detail table.

Comment: If I drop these two column from detail table then how I will get vendor details  using joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove countries and materials columns from Details table.

You can create a fourth table which will depict the relationship between vendor,country and material:

```
vendor_id   country_id   material_id
   1            3            5
   1            6            9
   1            7            24
```

Here all the columns will be foreign key and together they will form composite primary key

Comment: I'm not sure we need a fourth table, i.e. the above table you are suggesting can becomes the new `details` table +1

Comment: In that case vendor name would get repeated in each row leading to data redundancy.
As per the data shown in question a vendor can deal in multiple countries and in multiple materials.

Comment: You're right...I wasn't thinking of the vendor name.  Yes, there should be a separate vendor table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to design two new tables `detail_country` and `detail_material` also you need to modify your `detail` table as fellow

```
detail           : id , vendor

detail_country   : detail_id , country_id

detail_material  : detail_id , material_id
```